# How to use pinyin keyboard in a textarea when the value comes from a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running into a strange react issue with textareas! Currently our application sends a textarea's value from a parent component to its child, then the child component just renders the textarea (it does some other stuff but for simplicity sake). When that field receives an onInput event it will then update the parent with its new text. If you type in the field currently, the correct English characters make it up to the parent & back down to the child. However when using a pinyin keyboard (In my case, specifically mac's pinyin keyboard) the prompt is not brought up to select the Chinese characters. I was able to use the pinyin keyboard with an input and an onchange event, however our requirements specify a textarea. I attempted to use an onChange event & key press events with no luck. I was able to successfully reproduce the issue for class based & functional components, however our application's component uses class components. Any ideas on why exactly the pinyin keyboard prompt isn't displaying when typing in a textarea would be very appreciated!

Class Components: https://codepen.io/Zozoobaba/pen/poEgMoj

Functional Components: https://codepen.io/Zozoobaba/pen/yLaemga

```
class Field extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      previousText: props.text,
      currentText: props.text,
    };
    
    this.compareText = this.compareText.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      previousText: nextProps.text,
      currentText: nextProps.text,
    });
  }
  
  compareText(e){
    const { currentText } = this.state;
    const { value } = e.target;
   
    this.setState({previousText: currentText}, () => this.props.updateText(value))
    
  }
  
  render() {
    const { state } = this;
    return (
        <textarea 
          value={state.currentText}
          onInput={(e) => {this.compareText(e)}}
          />
    )
  }
}

const Appication = (props) => {
  const [textareaText, setTextareaText] = useState('');
  
  const updateText = (text) => {
    setTextareaText(text);
  }
  
  render() {
    // console.log(this.state.textareaText)
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <div className="header">
          <h1>Welcome!</h1>
          <p>Please provide your information below.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="inputcontainer">
          <div>{this.state.textAreaText}</div>
          <Field updateText={this.updateText} text={this.state.textareaText} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textareaText: '',
    }
    
    this.updateText = this.updateText.bind(this);
  }
  
  updateText(text){
    this.setState({textareaText: text})
  }
  
  render() {
    // console.log(this.state.textareaText)
    return (
      <div className="form">
        <div className="header">
          <h1>Welcome!</h1>
          <p>Please provide your information below.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="inputcontainer">
          <div>{this.state.textAreaText}</div>
          <Field updateText={this.updateText} text={this.state.textareaText} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to listen for event.type compositionend instead of updating the parent's state onchange.

[See this article for a full description of how to implement this in React.](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=e1f024d6-80d3-41fd-b83c-52e1c2deb354)

Comment: We still have to deploy the solution to test with Window's pinyin keyboard, however on mac that link seemed to get me where I was trying to go! I wasn't able to get it working as a controlled input, but as an uncontrolled input it works fine. Specifically this: https://github.com/eyesofkids/react-compositionevent/blob/master/uncontrolled/Ctextarea.js. Just implemented that as my text area component and it seems to work!

Comment: The link to this page is broken.  Can we get a mirror?